# Installing Docker on OpenSuse Linux

Tags: hadoop, docker, opensuse, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to install [Ambari on Docker](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-ambari) image on my laptop which has OpenSuse Leap 42.1 as host OS. According to the description on the GitHub this image is based on CentOS 6.0.

> This will start (and download if you never used it before) an image
>   based on centos-6 with pre-installed Ambari 2.1.0 ready to install HDP
>   2.3.

Does it mean that if I use this docker image it will install CentOS as VM first and then run the services within it or it will use my host OS (OpenSuse) and just install the services in docker container.

I read [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/) that

> Docker containers will not have any permanent storage unless you set
>   it up. When the container is killed, any data not found in the image
>   will be lost.

Does it mean all docker containers don't have persistent storage? If yes, how do I setup permanent storage for docker image?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that if I use this docker image it will install CentOS as
>   VM first and then run the services within it or it will use my host OS
>   (OpenSuse) and just install the services in docker container.

Docker images are different beasts compared to your host OS images. Basically docker has its own set of images and when you issue a `docker pull` command (in your case it will be issued indirectly, i guess) docker will download the required image, e.g. CentOS in your case. To be precise, when you specify an image, Docker looks first for the image on your Docker host. If it can’t find it then it downloads the image from its public image registry: Docker Hub.

> Does it mean all docker containers don't have persistent storage? If
>   yes, how do I setup permanent storage for docker image?

You can use `Data volumes` for persistent storage, which you shoud setup but it's an easy task! Read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/) for more details. In a nutshell:

> Data volumes are designed to persist data, independent of the
>   container’s life cycle. Docker therefore never automatically delete
>   volumes when you remove a container, nor will it “garbage collect”
>   volumes that are no longer referenced by a container.